# rails and scriptaculous appear effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous

I have a rails view with this html:

```
<body onload='<%= visual_effect(:appear, :main_counter, :duration=>3.0) %>'>  
  <div class="counter" id="main_counter">some content</div>
</body>
```

and a stylesheet:

```
.counter{ 
  opacity:0;
}
```

The effect works as expected but when its done the div's text disappears, I am guessing the opacity is going back to 0.
How can I make it stay with full opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the appear effect removes the the opacity style from the element once it's done. the easiest solution is to remove the `opacity: 0;` from the stylesheet and put it directly on the div with `style="opacity: 0"`. This is a little bit ugly, because of the inline style. Antoher solution would be to use the :from option in the visual_effect call like this:

```
visual_effect(:appear, :main_counter, :duration=>3.0, :from => 0)
```

This way the effect would first set the opacity to 0. However, if your pages takes a while to load, it could be that the div is visible until the on_load event gets fired.

I'm curious that I never stumbled upon that, It bugs me a little bit that I can not think of a "nice" solution.